Did the Trojan Horse story transpire?
In support that it happened:
+ neighboring countries confirm parts of the Iliad*  
+ described in detail down to soldiers' names  

Instead in support that it's fairy tale:
- (I believe) people weren't significantly dumber in the past, especially when it concerns their and their family's lives**  
- Iliad is a religious text instead of a historical log  
- the horse story allows both parties to save face instead of the more probable "Troy starved" or "a successful commando operation; there might even been a horse but not a hollow one"  
- my reading of the Wikipedia [article][1] 

Was a horse with soldiers inside accepted in the city of Troy?
* - "There are some parallels of the Trojan War mentioned in Hittite history with how an under-king or vassal in the West went through instability and was eventually beaten to death with his own child. This being directly tied to how Neoptolemus beat Priam to death with the kings infant son." unsourced but reasonable claim
** - Consider the following allegory. A mighty battleship is dominating it's area for 10 years. Then it's enemies send a boat with a postcard on it. The ship promptly pulls the shiny boat on deck.
1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trojan_Horse#Factual_explanations

How many men were needed to capture Troy? What would be the dimensions of such a structure? How would it have been built? How would it have been transported in one night to the gates of Troy?
With all these questions, I think the probability of Greeks building and using such a horse are about on par with the myth of Noah building an arch and transporting 2 of each animal in it.

@MasB pretty solid arguments! The comparison however is a bit stretched, Noah is impossible if any of modern biology science is to be respected; while people have invested in "horse" missions 1, 2, 3, 4.
